# Bitbucket Api with ssh access key as header to get total number of pull requests in java

Tags: java, spring-rest, bitbucket-server

I want to make a rest call to bitbucket api with ssh private key as header.For example the url is (http://bitbucket.com/rest/api/1.0/repos/testProject/pull-requests?state=OPEN).

Is there a way call this url with spring rest template and how to pass ssl access key as header.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about sending your private key to a server.  You should *never* do that.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it with SSH Access Key?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using SSH keys use Personal Access Tokens:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html

(Introduced in Bitbucket 5.5)

Then you could use code like this:

```
package com.company.bitbucket.tools.application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.company.bitbucket.tools.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import com.company.bitbucket.tools.ProjectValue;
import com.company.bitbucket.tools.Projects;
import com.company.bitbucket.tools.UserValue;
import com.company.bitbucket.tools.Users;

@Controller
public class ProjectController {

    public static String BITBUCKET_URL = "https://bitbucket.company.com/rest/api/latest/";
    public static String PROJECTS = "projects";
    public static String PERMISSIONS = "permissions/users?permission=PROJECT_ADMIN";
    public static String PAT = "<put your generated token in here>";

@RequestMapping(value={"/projects"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listProjects(){
    HashMap<String, String> list = getAdmins();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("projects");
    model.addObject("adminMap", list);
    return model;
}


private HashMap<String, String> getAdmins(){
    HashMap<String, String> projectMap = new HashMap<>();    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(new HttpRequestInterceptor("Authorization", "Bearer ".concat(PAT)));
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

    Projects projects = restTemplate.getForObject(BITBUCKET_URL.concat("projects?limit=100"), Projects.class);
    for(ProjectValue projectValue:  projects.getValues()) {
        String projectUrl = String.format("%s/%s/%s/%s", BITBUCKET_URL, PROJECTS, projectValue.getKey(), PERMISSIONS);
        Users users = restTemplate.getForObject(projectUrl, Users.class);
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (UserValue value: users.getValues()) {
            names.add(value.getUser().getDisplayName());
        }

        String commaSeparatedNames = String.join(", ", names);
        projectMap.put(projectValue.getName(), commaSeparatedNames);            
    }



    return projectMap;
}

}
```

This code gets a list of project admins using the rest api, but you could change to make whatever rest request you wish.

Comment: I did tried personal access tokens already but we want explore things with ssh private key. I have ssh rsa public key setup in bitbucket server and i have rsa private key which i wanted to use that and make a call to bitbucket server to get no of commits or no of pull requests of a particular repo. Can that private key set in JVM or liberty server and make rest calls to bitbucket api without bearer token or user credentials?